# PowerPivot change Data Sets dynamically

Tags: sql, database, powerpivot

I have many data series (series I use in the sum values box in my pivot chart) and many charts in PowerPivot. I want to be able to dynamically change the data series used for all charts in my worksheet. Is this possible?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a disconnected slicer to change your measure. Jason Thomas has a good [blog post](http://www.sqljason.com/2012/11/measure-selection-using-slicers-in.html) about this.

Create a table that lists the possible measures with a second column that orders them. Copy and paste it into your Power Pivot model. Do not create a relationship to other tables.

Create a calculated measure that selects the correct value based on the user selection.

```
MsrValue:=switch (TRUE,
Min ( Msr[MsrId] ) = 1,
[Measure1],
Min ( Msr[MsrId] ) = 2,
[Measure2]),
Min ( Msr[MsrId] ) = 3,
[Measure3] )
)
```

Add a slicer with the values from the measure column from your table. Connect your pivot tables and charts to the slicer.

Replace the measures in your pivot tables and charts with the new measure you created.

Comment: Thanks mmarie! This is a good start however can the calculated measure work dynamically as the number of columns increases? i.e. as measure 4 and 5 are added.

Comment: If you add measures, you will have to add them to the table and calculation.  But you could do this quickly while you I add the new measure.